# Why does Javascript not recognize my constructor?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, typeerror, router

I am having an issue where the script is not recognizing the constructor in the class and assumes that I am calling all the other functions as the constructions.

```
class Articles {
    constructor(dbName = ':memory:') {
        return(async() => {
            this.db = await sqlite.open(dbName)
            const sql =  //an Sql command goes here
            await this.db.run(sql)
            return this
        })()
    }
    async all() {
        const sql = 'SELECT users.user, articles.* FROM articles, users\
                        WHERE articles.userid = users.id;'
        const articles = await this.db.all(sql)
        for(const index in articles){
            if(articles[index].photo === null) articles[index].photo = 'avatar.jpg'
            const dateTime = new Date (articles[index].D&T)
            const date = `${dateTime.getDate()}/${dateTime.getMonth()+1}/${dateTime.getFullYear()}`
            articles[index].Date_Time = date
        }
        return articles
    }
    async add(data) {
        console.log('ADD')
        console.log(data)
        return true
    }
    async close() {
        await this.db.close()
    }
}
export default Articles
```

When I run this portion of the code:

```
router.post('/add', async ctx => {
    const a = await new Articles(dbName)
    try{
        await new a.add(ctx.request.body)
        return ctx.redirect('/?msg=new article added')
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        await ctx.render('error', ctx.hbs)
    } finally {
        new a.close()
    }
})
```

This is the error I getting:

[It Keeps telling me that the function is not a constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExFGj.png)

Can anyone please help

Comment: The error message is correct - "add" and "close" are not constructors, they are methods of your "Articles" class.  Therefore, you don't use the "new" keyword when you call them

Comment: Dude I freaking love you!!! I have been stuck on this for upwards of 8 hours now!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"add" and "close" are methods of your "Articles" class.  Don't use the "new" keyword when you call those methods

```
router.post('/add', async ctx => {
    const a = await new Articles(dbName)
    try{
        await a.add(ctx.request.body)    // <- don't need "new" here
        return ctx.redirect('/?msg=new article added')
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        await ctx.render('error', ctx.hbs)
    } finally {
        a.close()    // <- don't need "new" here
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. That was it!!